# Let $p$ and $q$ be odd primes and $n \geq 1$. If $q^m \text{ }\bigg{|}\text{ }(p^n-1)(p^{n-1}-1)\cdots(p-1)$ then $q^m<p^n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I wold like to prove the following statement.

> Let $p$ and $q$ be odd primes and $n \geq 1$. If $$q^m \text{
>  }\bigg{|}\text{ }(p^n-1)(p^{n-1}-1)\cdots(p-1)$$ then $q^m<p^n$.

I am not sure where to proceed. Induction on $n$?

Comment: Have you tried an induction argument? I haven't written down the details, but it seems like that should work pretty well

Comment: Let $k$ be the smallest $k$ such that $q \mid (p^k-1)$. You should then get that $q \mid (p^{rk}-1)\cdots (p^k-1)$, and no factor $q$ in the terms left out. Then use $p^k = 1 \mod q$ and look at $1+p^k + p^{2k} + \cdots + p^{rk} \mod q$ to determine when it has a factor of $q$. Use this to find all terms that can have a factor of $q$. This should be enough but I don't have time to write out the details.